# How to extend the ensemble methods in scikit-learn with a new learning algorithm

Tags: scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I have a new decision tree ensemble regression method algorithm I need to implement, and I would 
like to build on the infrastructure that the Python-based scikit-learn package provides if I can. I want to create a new type of base decision tree and a new way of combining them to make ensemble regression predictions.

The documentation for scikit-learn is focused on usage, not extension. I have looked at the code for the existing ensemble methods, but there is some fairly subtle Python-fu being used, which makes it hard to know where to start. Does anyone know of documentation that explains how to extend scikit with custom classes? Or is there an example of a simple extension of this kind? (It could be on any module; it doesn't have to be ensembles.)

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to roll both a new tree learner and a new ensemble method?

Comment: Yes that's right. I suppose the main change would be the tree learner, I might still want to use essentially the same algorithm for creating multiple trees and averaging their predictions. The tree learner itself would have the same parameters of node size, leaf size etc but use a different algorithm for learning and store more information.